# Create a Custom Search

Tags: php, custom-fields

I want to create a search in WordPress on basis of width, style, type and finish. I have created a custom post type to enter products. And using custom fields to add width, style type and finish for each product. Now I have written this code but its not filtering products.

```
<?php
    $width=$_POST['width'];
    list($first, $secnd)=split('-', $width);
    $sink=$_POST['type'];
    $finish=$_POST['finish'];
    $style=$_POST['style'];
?>

<ul class="vanity-collection">
    <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        $query=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'products',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key' => 'width',
                'value' => $first,
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'width',
                'value' => $secnd,
                'compare' => '=<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'sink-type',
                'value' => $sink,
                'compare' => '=<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'finish',
                'value' => $finish,
                'compare' => '=<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'style',
                'value' => $style,
                'compare' => '=<'
            )
        ));
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $product_img=get_the_ID();
    ?>
    <li>
        <div class="img-box">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $product_img,array(291,202,true)); ?>
            <a href="#" class="hover-collection"></a>
        </div>
        <span class="font-collection-detail"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    </li>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: thanx mate, the issue was that this code not filtering results... but I have found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in my code, I have to add another array before the meta arrays like this

```
$query=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'products',
            'meta_query' => array(
array(
                'key' => 'width',
                'value' => $first,
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'width',
                'value' => $secnd,
                'compare' => '=<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'sink-type',
                'value' => $sink,
                'compare' => '=<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'finish',
                'value' => $finish,
                'compare' => '=<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'style',
                'value' => $style,
                'compare' => '=<'
            )
)
        ));
```